# Setting session variables in a class is setting all of them, not just one

Tags: session, session-variables

I have been researching a way to set session variables for my Web App to store the logged in user's info.  I have made a lot of progress, being a novice, but I am stumped as to why setting the variables will set all of them and not just the one specified.  Can someone point out my mistake(s), please?  Thank you!!

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace ITHD
{
public class Common : Page
{

    public static void GetLoggedInUserProperties()
    {
        string gLoginId = ExtractUserName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
        SessionManager.LoginId = gLoginId;

        VerifyInAD(gLoginId);

    }
    private static void VerifyInAD(string sUser)
    {
        try
        {
            string userName = ExtractUserName(sUser);
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();

            search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", userName);

            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("MemberOf");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("phone");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            //SessionManager.CanEdit = "False";
            SessionManager.UserName = string.Empty;

            if (result != null)
            {
                SessionManager.UserName = string.Format("{0}", result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
                bool admin = checkGroup("Helpdesk Agents");
                if (admin == true)
                {
                    SessionManager.HDAgent = "True";
                }
            }
            search.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SessionManager.UserName = "Guest";
        }

    }

    public static string ExtractUserName(string path)
    {
        string[] userPath = path.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        return userPath[userPath.Length - 1];
    }
    public static bool checkGroup(string group)
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(group);
    }
}

public static class SessionManager
{
    private const string sLoginId = "";
    public static string LoginId
    {
        get
        {
            if (null != HttpContext.Current.Session[sLoginId])
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sLoginId] as string;
            else
                return "Guest";
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[sLoginId] = value;
        }
    }
    private const string sUserName = "";
    public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (null != HttpContext.Current.Session[sUserName])
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sUserName] as string;
            else
                return "Guest";
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[sUserName] = value;
        }
    }
    private const string sHDAgent = "";
    public static string HDAgent
    {
        get
        {
            if (null != HttpContext.Current.Session[sHDAgent])
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[sHDAgent] as string;
            else
                return "False";
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[sHDAgent] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are setting your session keys correctly. In your static class you have a property setter that is essentially session Session[""]=Some Value for all members. You do not need to set the key to the name of the private member in .net 3.5 you do not even need the private member. You could also just stuff the whole session object in and not worry about each member.

Then just access a Current instantiator of the properties as in

```
MySession.Current.UserName="guest";


public class MySession
{
    private const string _SessionName = "__MY_SESSION__";
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private MySession(){}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            MySession session =
                (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session[_SessionName];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                session.Property1 = new Property1();
                session.Property2 = new Property2();
                session.UserName = "";
                HttpContext.Current.Session[_SessionName] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Property1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public Property2 Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this code and it works great!  Thanks!  I am struggling a bit on the "session.Property1 = new Property1();" part since I have not done that before, so if that part can be explained so I can clear the "'ITHD.MySession.Property1' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'" error, that'd be great.  I will research it regardless.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would access each property using the Current property so that you get a reference to the single application wide MySession, thus updating the underlying session... Property1 something=ITHD.MySession.Current.Property1; Then changes to something would by reference update whatever is in the session.